# Warning when start riak

Tags: riak

When I start riak I get warning

> WARNING: ulimit -n is 1024; 65536 is the recommended minimum.

I have added

```
riak soft nofiles 65536
riak hard nofiles 65536
```

to `/etc/security/limits.conf` but it doesn't helped.

riak is runned under riak user

```
$ ps au | grep riak
riak      1892  1.1  4.9 1994024 102292 pts/1  Ssl+ 21:06   0:05 /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.10.3/bin/beam.smp -scl false -sfwi 500 -P 256000 -e 256000 -Q 65536 -A 64 -K true -W w -zdbbl 32768 -- -root /usr/lib/riak -progname riak -- -home /var/lib/riak -- -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/2.1.0/riak -config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2015.10.29.21.06.14.config -setcookie riak -name riak@127.0.0.1 -smp enable -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.10.29.21.06.14.args -pa /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches -- console
atcvetk+  2323  0.0  0.1  11748  2144 pts/0    S+   21:13   0:00 grep --color=auto riak
```

My question is how to make riak happy?

Comment: For a LDAP server on an older RHEL system, I ended up with a `ulimit -n 65536` line in its `/etc/sysconfig/dirsrv` file, though I don't know how you're starting that riak.

Comment: Riak is started with some startup script, `sudo service riak restart` reproduce my problem

Comment: have you tried running `ulimit -n` and `su -c "ulimit -n" riak` to verify the settings had the desired effect?